# Highcharts sankey diagrams multiple series

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

I would like to have multiple series in my sankey diagram so that the legend adjusts along.

[image]

For now, I have to have to trick with an empty `data` series:

```
series: [{
  name: 'New allocations',
  keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight', 'color'],
  data: sortedData,
  centerInCategory: true,
  showInLegend: true,
  color: 'pink',
  colorByPoint: false,
  nodes,
}, {
  name: 'Current allocations',
  keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight', 'color'],
  data: [], // Only added so that it is displayed in the legend :(
  centerInCategory: true,
  showInLegend: true,
  color: 'blue',
  colorByPoint: false,
  nodes,
}]
```

But it doesn't feel correct for color handling, nor tooltip content.

Thanks

Comment: You mean something like in this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q0L3jdy2/)?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Well, the example you submitted uses the same trick as I did, by not setting any data to legend series. But then, one can't hover the legend and see only related links, which would be the expected behavior. Shouldn't Highcharts merge the series at some point?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use [hide()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series.html#hide) and [show()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series.html#show) methods, another thing is to set the color to transparent.
Unfortunately, I don't see an option to not have the whole date in the following series because otherwise the series is added to the whole width of the chart.

```
  var series = chart.series[1];
  if (series.visible) {
    series.hide();
    e.target.innerHTML = 'Show apples';
  } else {
    series.show();
    e.target.innerHTML = 'Hide apples';
  }
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q0L3jdy2/3/

API References:

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series.html#hide

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series.html#show